# jQuery UI accordion - make individual FAQ speed the same as 'show all'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

Here I have a jQuery UI accordion:

http://jsfiddle.net/1e6z2ubp/3/

I would like to make the speed of each individual item opening, the same speed as when the 'show all' button is clicked.

The bit of js in question is below, but best to view the JSFiddle. I think the speed should be 100 if possible.

```
$(".faq-accordion > div").accordion({ header: "h4", collapsible: true, active: false, speed: 100, });
```

Comment: So I'm not sure what your problem is. You seem to have answered it. Just put in `100` instead of `10000`.

Comment: @philtune That doesn't seem to affect anything as the speed is still slower than when all are opened/collapsed at once